# Why this gives me a notice and warning when i add multiple choice answer what should i do?

Tags: php

array(4) { ["txt"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(11) "action word" [1]=> string(6) "nothing" [2]=> string(5) "just a word" [3]=> string(9) "i dont know" } ["radioans"]=> string(5) "txta1" ["btnadd"]=> string(0) "" ["h1"]=> string(2) "38" }

**Notice: Undefined index: txt[] in C:\xampp\htdocs\quiEZ\adminanswer.php on line 10**

> ```
> $answers=htmlspecialchars($_POST["txt[]"]);
> ```

**Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\quiEZ\adminans.php on line 15**

> ```
> foreach($answers as $key=>$ans){
> ```

```
<?php
$title = "QuiEZ - Add Answers";
include_once "includes/db.php";
include_once "includes/header.php";
if (!isset($_SESSION["userid"], $_SESSION["sid"], $_SESSION["userrole"]) || $_SESSION["userrole"] != "A") {
    header("Location:login.php");
}
if (isset($_POST["btnadd"])) {
    var_dump($_POST);
    $answers=htmlspecialchars($_POST["txt[]"]);
    $rightans=(int) preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', filter_input(INPUT_POST,"radioans"));
    $aqid=filter_input(INPUT_POST,"h1");
    $db = new db;
    $link = $db->dbconnect();
    foreach($answers as $key=>$ans){
        if($key+1==$rightans){
            $qry="insert tbans values(null,$aqid,'$ans','T','".date('Y/m/d')."')";
        }else{
            $qry="insert tbans values(null,$aqid,'$ans','F','".date('Y/m/d')."')";
        }
        mysqli_query($link,$qry);
        header("Location:admques.php");
    }
}

?>

    <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-hover uk-card-body uk-width-1-2@m uk-width-1-2@s uk-align-center uk-margin-auto@s uk-margin-remove-bottom">
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET["qid"])) {
        ?>
        <form method="post" class="uk-width-auto" action="admans.php">
            <legend class="uk-legend">Answers</legend>
            <div class="uk-width-1-1@s">
                <?php
                $db = new db;
                $link = $db->dbconnect();
                $qry = "select * from tbque where qid=" . filter_input(INPUT_GET, "qid");
                $res = mysqli_query($link, $qry);
                $r = mysqli_fetch_row($res);
                echo "<h2>$r[1]</h2>";
                mysqli_free_result($res);
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="uk-margin">
                <input class="uk-input" name="txt[]"
                       type="text"
                       placeholder="Answer 1.." required>
                RIGHT ANSWER OR NOT? <input class="uk-radio" value="txta1" name="radioans" type="radio">
            </div>
            <div class="uk-margin">
                <input class="uk-input" name="txt[]"
                       placeholder="Answer 2.." required>
                RIGHT ANSWER OR NOT? <input class="uk-radio" value="txta2" name="radioans" type="radio">

            </div>
            <div class="uk-margin">
                <input class="uk-input" name="txt[]"
                       placeholder="Answer 3.." required>
                RIGHT ANSWER OR NOT? <input class="uk-radio" value="txta3" name="radioans" type="radio">

            </div>
            <div class="uk-margin">
                <input class="uk-input" name="txt[]"
                       placeholder="Answer 4.." required>
                RIGHT ANSWER OR NOT? <input class="uk-radio" value="txta4" name="radioans" type="radio">
            </div>
            <div class="uk-align-center uk-text-center">
                <button type="submit" name="btnadd" class="uk-button-large uk-button-primary">ADD</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="h1" value="<?=filter_input(INPUT_GET,"qid")?>"/>
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php
        $qid = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "qid");
        $qry = "SELECT atxt FROM `tbans` where aqid=$qid";
        $res = mysqli_query($link, $qry);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($res)) {
            ?>
            <table class="uk-table uk-table-divider uk-table-responsive uk-width-auto">
                <caption>Answers</caption>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <?php
                    $i = 1;
                    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_row($res)) {
                        ?>
                        <td><strong><?= $i ?>. <span class="uk-text-bolder"><?= $r[0] ?></span></strong></td>
                        <?php
                        $i++;
                    }
                    mysqli_free_result($res);
                    ?>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <?php
        }
    } else {
        if (isset($msg)) {
            echo $msg;
        } else {
            echo "NOTHING HERE!";
        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask], and pay attention to what it has to say about question titles. “please help me to figure out this one” is a really, really bad one.

Comment: This `$answers=htmlspecialchars($_POST["txt[]"]);` should be `$answers=htmlspecialchars($_POST["txt"]);`

Comment: @Dave i did that and it shows **Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in**

Comment: You need to use `htmlspecialchars` in your `foreach` and operate on each input field not the entire array of values.

Comment: @Dave how do i do that? i'm kinda confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POST value of `txt` is an array that you can't use with `htmlspecialchars`. If you really want to use `htmlspecialchars` do it as you go through each of the values in the array in your `foreach` loop.

```
$answers=$_POST["txt"];
$rightans=(int) preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', filter_input(INPUT_POST,"radioans"));
$aqid=filter_input(INPUT_POST,"h1");
$db = new db;
$link = $db->dbconnect();
foreach($answers as $key=>$ans){
$ans = htmlspecialchars($ans);
if($key+1==$rightans){
        $qry="insert tbans values(null,$aqid,'$ans','T','".date('Y/m/d')."')";
    }else{
        $qry="insert tbans values(null,$aqid,'$ans','F','".date('Y/m/d')."')";
    }
    mysqli_query($link,$qry);
}
header("Location:admques.php");
```

I should also point out that your `header` call is in your `foreach` loop but you probably want it after the `foreach` is finished. If not you will only ever process one answer.

Comment: thank you so much for your help @Dave! I did exactly what you showed above and it works! there is one more thing i need to, it is to update the multiple choice answers they should be overwritten.

Comment: Don't understand your comment/additional question at all. It's probably best for you to frame a new question with the appropriate code.

Comment: what i mean is, since this is already functioning i wanna add another function(button) which can update(overwrite) the answers that I've added.

Answer (score 0):

Txt[] should be an array, the key should be txt and not Txt[]

Use var_dump to see your values and work with that.

`if (!empty($_POST)) var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: it shows me this **Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in** i changed txt[] to txt $answers=htmlspecialchars($_POST["txt"]);

Comment: Keep dumping with var_dump and you will find the issue eventually